# sql update part string and trim trailing value

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to update a string but I also need to wipe out the rest of the values following the found string.  I can't use the replace since the value at the end will change but the middle part will stay the same for many records.  I haven't seen a post for removing the trailing portion of a string if you don't know it's exact value or location within the string.
I am using Oracle for my database thru SQL Developer to update the data.

```
"keep this data" "search on keyword" "wipe out trailing data"     "result data"
xyz                 @                     psu.edu                 xyz
```

Column data value = xyz@psu.edu

I would search for a record with columnname like '@%'

Remove "@%"

End result value = xyz

Column data value = ABCabc123

I would search for a record with columnname like 'abc%'

Remove "abc%"

End result value = ABC

I have not seen any answers with this type of update.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr('xyz@psu.edu',1, instr('xyz@psu.edu','@') - 1) from dual

select substr('ABCabc123',1, instr('ABCabc123','abc') - 1) from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check in case the string you want is not found:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN INSTR('xyz@psu.edu','@', 1, 1) > 0
             THEN SUBSTR('xyz@psu.edu',1,INSTR('xyz@psu.edu','@', 1, 1)-1)
             ELSE 'xyz@psu.edu'
          END as "Result Data"
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thank you.  How can I run this type of query against my column in the table for updating thousands of records?

Comment: Just change the constant in the answer to the column name of your table (and name your table of course, and not use `DUAL`).